# Implementing reCaptcha into javascript validated form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, recaptcha

I have the following form and I'm using javascript to validate the form fields *onsubmit*. How would I implement **reCaptcha** into this form? Would I have to change the *onsubmit* value to execute a php file with the recaptcha validation and field validation together? Here is the current form:

```
    <form id="breeders" method="post" action="add-breeder?process" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Name:<br />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br /><br />
    County:<br />
    <select id="address" name="address">
  <option value="Antrim">Antrim</option>
<option value="Armagh">Armagh</option>
</select><br/>
    <br />Please select a point on the map nearest to you.<br />
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" />
    Phone No:<br />
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" /><br /><br />
    Description:<br />
    <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="breeds" id="breeds" /></textarea><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" value="Add Breeder" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
    </form>

   </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
       function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["breeders"]["name"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("Name is required.");
      return false;
      }

      var x=document.forms["breeders"]["address"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("Location is required.");
      return false;
      }

       var x=document.forms["breeders"]["phone"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("Contact phone number is required.");
      return false;
      } 

        var x=document.forms["breeders"]["breeds"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("A description of Breeds is required.");
      return false;
      }  

        var x=document.forms["breeders"]["lat"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("You have to select a location on the map.");
      return false;
      }

         var x=document.forms["breeders"]["lng"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("You have to select a location on the map.");
      return false;
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Any help appreciated, cheers!

**Edit:**

I have implemented reCaptcha on the form, but when I click submit the *action* doesn't seem to be executing. The file "submit.php" is in the same root. Here is the form code with reCaptcha:

```
        <form id="breeders" method="post" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Name:<br />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br /><br />
    County:<br />
    <select id="address" name="address">
  <option value="Antrim">Antrim</option>
<option value="Armagh">Armagh</option>
</select><br/>
    <br />Please select a point on the map nearest to you.<br />
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" />
    Phone No:<br />
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" /><br /><br />
    Description:<br />
    <textarea cols="40" rows="5" name="breeds" id="breeds" /></textarea><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<script type="text/javascript"
   src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY">
 </script>
 <noscript>
   <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=MY_PUBLIC_KEY"
       height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
 </noscript>

    <br/><input type="submit" value="Add Breeder" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
    </form>

   </div>
```

And here is the contents of the "submit.php" file:

```
<?php if (!defined('APPLICATION')) exit(); ?>

<?php
 require_once('recaptchalib.php');
 $privatekey = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";
 $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                 $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
 if (!$resp->is_valid) {
   // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
   die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
        "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
 } else {
   // Your code here to handle a successful verification
 }
 ?>

  <?php
//connection to my database details etc.
?>


  <?php
if(isset($_GET['process']))
{
$query = "Insert INTO `markers` (name, address, lat, lng, phone, breeds) values('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[address]','$_POST[lat]','$_POST[lng]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[breeds]')";
//echo $query; exit;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(!$result)
{
$msg = "not Inserted";
}
else
{
$msg = "Inserted";
header("location:breeders?m=".$msg);
}
}

?>
```

"recaptchalib.php is also in the same folder. You can check out the form here: http://poultry.ie/add-breeder

Answer (score 0):

The CAPTCHA has to be validated server side when you are submitting your data for it to be secure at all. You can keep your validation in Javascript so long as you are aware that it is not enforced at all and there is nothing to stop a malicious user from sending whatever nonsensical rubbish to your server side script that they want. It is generally good practice to validate server side when possible but it depends on who's benefit you are doing the validation for.

Comment: I'm validating the form client side using javascript so that the user inputting the data can't actually submit their data until it is correctly filled in (required fields, number, location selected) as an alert pops up (`onsubmit="return validateForm()"`). Then I'm validating the reCaptcha server side with php in a separate file which is called through this (`action="submit.php"`). Is that good practise? My knowledge of php isn't great.

Answer (score 0):

Goopps! Read out this http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/HowToSetUpRecaptcha 
 Mainly at **Part 2: Installation** then yours choice!

**Towards your Error**

change  `action="submit.php?process=1"` in form 
have you  `defined('APPLICATION')` ?

**update:**

```
Insert INTO `markers`  to Insert INTO markers 
(in the Above Note: "`" )
```

try Echoing to know where execution stops!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've implemented the reCaptcha code but I seem to be having problems with file referencing, or more likely just bad coding on my part! I've edited the original post with more information.

Comment: ok! your page seems submitting correctly  , Simply, Returned :- POST submit.php 200 OK poultry.ie 0 B 46.22.129.107:80,look on , i have edited the  answer

Comment: I changed action to what you suggested above but still no change. Also realised I should have been putting my database details and code for inserting users data into the database in the space where it says "  // Your code here to handle a successful verification". Still no change though after I did that.

Comment: `<?php if (!defined('APPLICATION')) exit(); ?>` is to do with Vanilla the software the site is run on. I'm using a [plugin](http://vanillaforums.org/addon/custompages-plugin) to create the add-breeder page, maybe it is causing the problem?

Comment: i think , its better to echo logs at some points , especially before the exit();,(!$resp->is_valid),.... and check actually where the execution stops